# Rails - Wordpress SSO - Single-Sign On

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, single-sign-on

I'm trying to achieve an integration between a Rails app (the core of my website, at domain.com and www.domain.com) and a Wordpress Network (multisite, at *.domain.com).

For that I need to build a Single Sign On process.

I have found a plugin : [Rails Integration Api](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rails-integration-api/), but i didn't find the article or readme describing the rails part. The process is based on the recuperation of the cookie, created in rails.

So my questions will be :

- Do you know any pointers to achieve a Rails - Wordpress SSO integration ?
- Do you know some good resources about implementing Wordpress SSO, for any backend ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin looks like it's looking to the cookie set by your Rails app. If you look at the cookies that are set after you login to that app, do any of them jump out at you as being the auth session cookie?

Also, here's the article referenced in the plugin about configuring the Rails side: http://web.archive.org/web/20090116063054/http://greenfabric.com/page/integration_api_home_page

It looks like it's been defunct for a while (only available thru archive.org) but maybe that will help you put the puzzle together.

Comment: Thanks for the research.
I've found the rails plugin on github [here](https://github.com/gravis/integration_api). After some adaptations for rails3 / devise / wordpress multisite, and some security changes, all is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post outlining setting up Wordpress as an Oauth provider and authenticating a rails application against it. http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/02/18/single-sign-on-with-rails-wordpress-and-oauth2/